# Question regarding the density function of first n prediction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayesian

This is an example from Bertsekas' Introduction to Probability 2nd edition example 8.2

Consider now a variation involving the first $n$ dates. Assume that Juliet is late by random amounts $$X_1, \ldots, X_n$$ which given $\Theta = \theta$ are uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, \theta]$ and conditionally independent. Let $$X = (X_1, \ldots,  X_n)$$ and $$x = (x_1, \ldots,  x_n)$$

The parameter $\theta$ is unknown and is modeled as the value of a random variable $\theta$ uniformly distributed between zero and one hour.

Why is

$$f_{X \mid \theta}(x\mid \theta) =  \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\theta^n}  & \bar{x} \leq \theta \leq 1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

$$\bar{x} = \max(x_1, \ldots,  x_n)$$

shouldn't $f_{X \mid \theta}(x\mid \theta)$ base on the distribution of $X$ instead of taking the max?

Comment: There is nothing in what you've told us that is a reason when $\theta$ must be $\le 1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, I edited more info

Comment: Properly speaking one should have $f_{X\mid\theta}$ rather than $f_{x\mid\theta}$.  If for example, $x = 0.2$, then the value of the foregoing expression is $f_{X\mid\theta}(0.2)$, not $f_{0.2\mid\theta}(0.2)$.  The capital $X$ identifies which random variable it is; the lower-case $x$ is the thing that could assume the value $0.2$ and be an argument to the density function.  Without distinguishing between $X$ and $x$, one cannot even understand what $\Pr(X\le x)$ means. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You must have meant "conditionally independent _given_ $\theta$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, there isn't really a need to write $f_{X\mid\theta}(x\mid\theta)$; one can write $f_{X\mid\theta}(x)$.  the subscript identifies which distribution it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, then their joint density $f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is equal to $f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdots f_{X_n}(x_n)$.  In this case, for every index $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and every value of $x>0$, we have
$$
f_{X_i}(x) = \begin{cases} 1/\theta & \text{if }x<\theta, \\ 0 & \text{if }x>\theta. \end{cases}
$$
Multiplying those gives $(1/\theta)^n$ if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are all $<\theta$.  But if even one $x_i$ is $>\theta$, then you're multiplying a $0$ by the other factors and getting $0$.  To say that for **every** $i$ we have $x_i<\theta$ is to say that $\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}<\theta$.

Comment: so technically $x$ should also be $> 0$ ? since $\frac{1}{\theta}$ is undefined when $\theta = 0 $ ?

Comment: Actually one doesn't worry about how the density is defined at an individual point, since changing its value at just one point (such as the endpoints $0$ or $\theta$) does not change the values of any integrals. One can say that the density of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }0<x<1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$ and how it's defined at the two enpoints isn't even really a question. One could say that there's a uniform distribution for which $\theta=0$, but it is the degenerate distribution that puts probability $1$ at $0$ and${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots$ morever that is a _discrete_ distribution so one doesn't define it by a density with respect to the usual measure on the line. ${}\qquad{}$